# Dynamic row height for CardViews in a RecyclerView based on text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I wish to make a CardView that dynamically resizes itself based on the text content (i.e. when the text is too long for certain screens and needs to be multiline).

Desired (this was achieved by modifying the `lines` attribute to 2):
[image]

However, in both testing and previews, this is what happens:
[image]'

I'm not sure what are the possible approaches to solve this issue. Must the `lines` attribute be programmatically set, or is there something wrong with my XML layout, or an issue with some of the settings of the RecyclerView? My RecyclerView uses the simple `LinearLayoutManager` as its LayoutManager.

The XML of the CardView is available below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_uav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:tint="#4b4b4b"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_quadcopter" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uav_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Telemedicine Drone Approaching!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/uav_eta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:format24Hour="mm:ss"
            android:text="00:23"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="ETA:"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you do not want to stick to `ConstraintLayout` a  `LinearLayout` simply can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Make your list row **CardView** wrap_content in your context. Though you can dynamically add height of the content in recycler view inside onBindViewHolder as follow

```
 float proportionalHeight = getScreenWidth(yourViewHeight.getHeight(), yourViewWidth.getWidth());

                    if (proportionalHeight > 380) {
                        proportionalHeight = 380;
                    }

                    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, proportionalHeight, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) px);
                    yourMainView.setLayoutParams(params);


private float getScreenWidth(int height, int width) {

            Configuration configuration = getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration();
            float screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp;
            float check = (float) height / width;
            Log.e("TAG", "getScreenWidth: " + screenWidthDp);
            Log.e("TAG", "return: " + check * screenWidthDp);
            return check * screenWidthDp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_uav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:tint="#4b4b4b"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_quadcopter" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uav_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Telemedicine Drone!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ETA:"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Large"
                   />
                <TextClock
                    android:id="@+id/uav_eta"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:format24Hour="mm:ss"
                    android:text="00:23"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                  />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

replace above code with your existing, its hard for me to manage `ConstraintLayout` with mouse, so i changed it to `LinearLayout`, this will do what you want to achieve.